# Using makefile file as prerequisite in a rule

Tags: c, makefile, build

I am inexperienced with make, and wanted to replicate a build structure provided by some third-party SDK and adapt it to my own compiler and project.

The thing is that I found that some rules are generated using the makefile as prerequisite, something like:

```
...
$(eval $(1): Makefile | $(dir $(1)).) \
...
```

or

```
$(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/%.inc: Makefile | $(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
    $(info Generating $@)
    $(NO_ECHO)$(call dump, $(call target_specific, INC_PATHS, $*)) > $@
```

Originally, their makefile is Capitalized (*Makefile*) and the one I am working on is lowercase (*makefile*). Anyway, When I try my current changes, this error appears:

```
*** No rule to make target 'Makefile', needed by '...'
```

I supposed that was due to the capitalization, so changed to lowercase in both places and tried again, but this time the error is that the makefile is treated as a C file (This is my guess...)

```
"makefile", line 1: error #171: expected a declaration
  -include makefile.local
                          ^

"makefile", line 67: error #8: missing closing quote
  ${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/include"
                         ^

"makefile", line 99: error #10: "#" not expected here
  .SUFFIXES: # ignore built-in rules
             ^

"makefile", line 100: error #10: "#" not expected here
  %.d:       # don't try to make .d files
             ^

"makefile", line 100: error #8: missing closing quote
  %.d:       # don't try to make .d files
```

What could be the issue here? Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT 1:**
These are the files I am trying to use.

Nordic provides these as part of their SDK for development using arm-gcc for ARM platforms. There is a `Makefile` per project and there is a `Makefile.common` included in the main `Makefile`.

- [Makefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSOVO43itK-QttuV9NWEm9ufrfjG9wJL/view?usp=sharing)
- [Makefile.common](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mz3MYmOrKLmzyTQv_tHQYyePxwgoaMLo/view?usp=sharing)

On the other side, I am trying to understand and replicate the same but for another proprietary compiler with different options and syntax (TI's cl430 for MSP430 platforms). From the original `Makefile.common` I removed some references to the gnu-arm suite and replace it with the proper compiling tools. In the `makefile` I also tried to replicate the same structure of the original but using my sources and options.

- [makefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16oqUd07tuK9rAmGr4bk0FwpOULAmCADK/view?usp=sharing)
- [makefile.common](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EFOLZYlJg4E5awe5glAXJbUPv7juCQb1/view?usp=sharing)

Just to make it clear, originals are capitalized, mine are lowercase.

**EDIT 2:**

After running `make --debug --print-data-base` I found this:

The error appears in the first attempt to build a file:

```
Updating goal targets....
 File 'default' does not exist.
   File 'test_project' does not exist.
     File '_build/test_project.out' does not exist.
       File '_build/test_project/<SOURCE_FILE>.c.o' does not exist.
      Must remake target '_build/test_project/<SOURCE_FILE>.c.o'.
Building file: "makefile"
Invoking: MSP430 Compiler
"cl430" -vmspx --use_hw_mpy=F5 <... a lot of options ...> --obj_directory="./_build"  "makefile"
"makefile", line 1: error #171: expected a declaration
  -include makefile.local
  ^
[ ... more errors ...]
```

However, from the debug and DB information, I found that the source file rule indeed requires makefile, and that makefile is not a target, but somehow it is trying to build it:

```
# Not a target:
makefile:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Last modified 2020-02-25 11:43:33.609423171
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.

_build/test_project/<SOURCE_FILE>.c.o: makefile | _build/test_project/.
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: '_build/test_project/<SOURCE_FILE>'
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has been updated.
#  Failed to be updated.
# automatic
# @ := _build/test_project/<SOURCE_FILE>.c.o
# automatic
# % := 
# automatic
# * := _build/test_project/<SOURCE_FILE>
# automatic
# + := makefile
# automatic
# | := _build/test_project/.
# automatic
# < := makefile
# automatic
# ^ := makefile
# automatic
# ? := makefile
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/30=3%
#  recipe to execute (from 'makefile.common', line 192):
    @echo 'Building file: "$<"'
    @echo 'Invoking: MSP430 Compiler'
    "${CG_TOOL_ROOT}/bin/cl430" -vmspx --use_hw_mpy=F5 <... a lot of options ...> "$(shell echo $<)"
    @echo 'Finished building: "$<"'
    @echo ' '
```

Comment: The error reported for line 67 shows that you removed a quotation sign too much. There might be more errors, compare your version with the original. -- BTW, the traditional name is "Makefile" capitalized.

Comment: You didn't show "the whole" reproducible example but make isn't stupid and normally will interpret `makefile` and `Makefile` equally. In this case [What Name to Give Your Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html) should be irrelevant as _by default, when make looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile.(We recommend Makefile because it appears prominently near the beginning of a directory listing, right near other important files such as README.)_

Comment: Also the `*** No rule to make target 'Makefile', needed by '...'` means your Makefile figures as some kind of target so make wants to generate it, just as any object file, and seeks for rule to do that.

As your Makefile you presented is a bit "incomplete" we cannot help much more.

Comment: @tansy thanks for your comments, I added the source files if this is of any help.

Comment: Run `make` with `--debug --print-data-base` options to see what needs `Makefile`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, question updated with debug information.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh That `<SOURCE_FILE>` doesn't look right, locate and examine its rule.

Comment: Well the issue is that the rules are auto-generated using the `makefile.common` file. In the main `makefile` it is defined the variable `SRC_FILES` listing all the source files and used for creating the rules for building them.

Comment: "_I found that the source file rule indeed requires makefile, and that makefile is not a target_". It is a target, intermediate but a target and there is no rule to build it (it's empty).

Comment: There are so many other issues there, like toolchain template (`TOOLCHAIN_CONFIG_FILE := $(TEMPLATE_PATH)/Makefile.$(PLATFORM_SUFFIX)`). Do you have it at all? (will be either `Makefile.windows` or `Makefile.posix`). It is so complicated that you should use "original" auto-generator if possible or you will be doing this for the next week.

Comment: The `Makefile.platform` just creates a variable to define where the toolchain is located. As I said before I cannot use the `makefile.common` as is because the toolchain I'm intending to use is completely different regarding compiler and linker options, syntax and outputs. From the debug output I saw this line `# < := makefile` and guess that in order to work it should be `# < := <SOURCE_FILE>.c`

Answer (score 3):

That dependency on `Makefile` is to make sure that it rebuilds when `Makefile` has been changed. For example, if you change `CFLAGS` in `Makefile` or a rule to compile or link, this dependency triggers a rebuild (provided object files depend on `Makefile`, as they should). Without dependency on `Makefile` those changes won't cause a rebuild.

The error messages in the form of `"makefile", line 1: error #171: expected a declaration` suggest that `makefile` is passed as a source file to a C compiler that produces the error message.

The rules most likely do `$(filter-out Makefile,$^)`. You need to replace all occurrences of `Makefile` to `makefile`.

`*** No rule to make target 'Makefile', needed by '...'` means that `Makefile` is still a prerequisite of some targets. You can find what those targets are by passing `--debug --print-data-base` command line options to `make`.

Comment: To me it looks more like automatic Makfile generation rather than _making sure that it rebuilds when Makefile has been changed_. Make **will** reinterpret Makefile everytime it's run.

Comment: @tansy _Make will reinterpret `Makefile` everytime_ - that is right, however, it won't rebuild anything if `Makefile` changed but nothing depends on it. `make` handles generated `Makefile` automatically, see [3.5 How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles). If you update `CFLAGS` in the `Makefile`, for example, it won't rebuild anything without the dependency of object files on `Makefile`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, Thanks for your answer. That's what I was thinking, that is used for rebuild in case of `makefile` changes. I have updated the question with the source files. I found a reference for `filter-out` command but is not used with `makefile`.